# The tropical integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tropical-geometry

Let
\begin{align}
    \oplus_\mathbb{N} &= + \\
    0_\mathbb{N} &= 0 \\
    \odot_\mathbb{N} &= \cdot \\
    1_\mathbb{N} &= 1
\end{align}
Then $(\mathbb{N}, \oplus_\mathbb{N}, 0_\mathbb{N}, \odot_\mathbb{N}, 1_\mathbb{N})$ is the ordinary rig of natural numbers. Let $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{N}^2 / \sim$ where
\begin{align}
    (a_1, a_2) \sim (b_1, b_2) &\iff a_1 \oplus_\mathbb{N} b_2 =a_2 \oplus_\mathbb{N} b_1 \\
    (a_1, a_2) \oplus_\mathbb{Z} (b_1, b_2) &= (a_1 \oplus_\mathbb{N} b_1, a_2 \oplus_\mathbb{N} b_2) \\
    0_\mathbb{Z} &= [(0_\mathbb{N}, 0_\mathbb{N})]_\sim \\
    \ominus_\mathbb{Z} (a_1, a_2) &= (a_2, a_1) \\
    (a_1, a_2) \odot_\mathbb{Z} (b_1, b_2) &= ((a_1 \odot_\mathbb{N} b_1) \oplus_\mathbb{N} (a_2 \odot_\mathbb{N} b_2), (a_1 \odot_\mathbb{N} b_2) \oplus_\mathbb{N} (a_2 \odot_\mathbb{N} b_1)) \\
    1_\mathbb{Z} &= [(1_\mathbb{N}, 0_\mathbb{N})]_\sim
\end{align}
Then $(\mathbb{Z}, \oplus_\mathbb{Z}, 0_\mathbb{Z}, \ominus_\mathbb{Z}, \odot_\mathbb{Z}, 1_\mathbb{Z})$ is the ordinary ring of integers. Suppose we let
\begin{align}
    \oplus_\mathbb{N} &= \max \\
    0_\mathbb{N} &= 0 \\
    \odot_\mathbb{N} &= + \\
    1_\mathbb{N} &= 0
\end{align}
instead. This makes $(\mathbb{N}, \oplus_\mathbb{N}, 0_\mathbb{N}, \odot_\mathbb{N}, 1_\mathbb{N})$ the *tropical* rig of natural numbers. Call $(\mathbb{Z}, \oplus_\mathbb{Z}, 0_\mathbb{Z}, \ominus_\mathbb{Z}, \odot_\mathbb{Z}, 1_\mathbb{Z})$ the "tropical integers". Which papers, if any, have studied this structure? Does it have a geometric or easily-visualizable interpretation?

Comment: What is rig?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JCAA https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig

Comment: Please check if my edits are right

Comment: And what is tropical rig?

Comment: @JCAA The [max-plus algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/max-plus+algebra) restricted to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How exactly are you defining the "tropical integers"?  The definition you gave for going from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ does not work, since $\sim$ will not be an equivalence relation.  Do you just mean "freely turn the rig into a ring"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Well you can define it by a universal property (and then it is easy to prove it exists as some quotient of a set of formal words).  For a useful concrete construction, I think all you need to change is to strengthen the equivalence relation to say $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if there is some $e$ such that $a+d+e=b+c+e$.

Comment: As for the "integers" tag, I don't find it to be a particularly useful tag.  But to the extent it is useful, I think it is best reserved for questions about basic structural/axiomatic properties of the ordinary integers.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes, it does.  That's no surprise; tropical addition satisfies $x+x=x$, and so nothing good is going to happen when you adjoin additive inverses.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, sorry, I just realized I misread your comments and you didn't claim that the tropical naturals *embed* into some ring. I was worried I was going crazy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing like this works.

The starting point is the observation that the "max-version" of $\sim$ doesn't behave well at all:

- It's not an equivalence relation since it's non-transitive: we have e.g. $(1,0)\sim(2,2)$ and $(2,2)\sim (0,1)$ but $(1,0)\not\sim(0,1)$.
- More generally, whenever $c>a,b$ we have $(a,b)\sim(c,c)$. So the transitive closure of $\sim$ is everything.

Motivated by this specific observation we can in fact prove a general impossibility result:

> Every rig homomorphism from $T=(\mathbb{N};\max,+)$ to a rig $R$ which happens to be a ring has trivial image (= sends everything to the additive identity of $R$).

The point is this: for each $m\in T$ there is some $n\in T$ such that $m+n=n$. But then if $f:T\rightarrow R$ is a rig homomorphism we have $f(m)+f(n)=f(n)$, so since $R$ happens to be a ring we have $f(m)=0$. (In fact, all we need about $R$ is that it have the *cancellation* property for addition.)

Comment: Another fact with the same proof: If a rig satisfies $1+1=1$ then any homomorphism to a rig with additive cancellation is 0 (and so freely extending such a rig to a ring destroys it).